# Why are my images stored as MySQL longblobs only being displayed partially?

Tags: mysql, image

A client has just asked me to fix an issue with their webside.  I did not build it but here is what's happening.

The images are stored in the db as longblobs.  Before moving to a new server, everything was working a ok.  On the new server, **some** images only display partially.  Even though the image is displayed at desired width and height, over a half of the image is either white or gray.  **EDIT: Only images uploaded after the server change are affected!**

This is used for reading the image into a string for db insertion:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile1']['tmp_name'],"tmppic.img")) 
$tmpstr = fopen("tmppic.img","rb");
$image = addslashes(fread($tmpstr,filesize("tmppic.img")));
```

Here are the PHP functions used for displaying the images:
    imagecreatefromstring, 
    imagecreatetruecolor, 
    imagecopyresampled, 
    imagejpeg

Since this has started happening after the server move, I am suspecting server configuration.

What is going on?

Comment: Ok, so only some images are affected, and only images uploaded since the server change display incorrectly. Do ALL images uploaded since the server change display incorrectly or only some?

Comment: This will be important in determining whether the issue is indeed sporadic or if it occurs in an easily repeatable fashion.

Comment: @gabriel1836, only some of the images are affected.

Comment: can you duplicate it with one (or more) of your files? if so, what do these files have in common? large size? what is the first part that gets truncated? similarities?

Comment: Can you change the script for testing so that uploaded files are simply stored on the server? I would recommend this as a next step so that you can verify whether the actual upload of files is occurring correctly.

Comment: If they are, then next use SHOW VARIABLES in MySQL and compare the run-time settings between the two servers.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Figured it out.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  Looking at the code below.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile1']['tmp_name'],"tmppic.img")){
$tmpstr = fopen("tmppic.img","rb");
$image = addslashes(fread($tmpstr,filesize("tmppic.img")));
```

The uploaded file is moved into the tmppic.img file.  That file is constantly used.  The problem is that filesize("tmppic.img") is returning the size of the file **before** `move_uploaded_file`.  So, if the previous tmppic.img had a 120k filesize and the new uploaded file is larger, only 120K worth of info is read, thus the gray area in the pictures.

I fixed the issue by replacing filesize("tmppic.img") with

```
$file_size = $_FILES['imagefile1']['size'];
$image = mysql_real_escape_string(fread($tmpstr,$file_size));
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: If you're reading the whole file into memory, might as well just use `file_get_contents($_FILES['imagefile1']['tmp_name'])` (spares you messing around with temp files and file handles).

Answer (score 3):

Dunno if it's what's killing you, but you definitely need to change the `addslashes()` to `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  SQL injection ahoy...

Answer (score 2):

MAKE SURE your image fields are set to the right BLOB type.

I had the same issue and it was a dead simple solution; I had my image field set to "Blob" as opposed to "LongBlob." My DB couldn't allocate enough space in the field to store the image data. Changed it to LongBlog and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible the data got corrupted during the server move - especially if the data was dumped and then re-inserted. Can you confirm the entire image data is actually in the database?

Edit: Just saw your edit to the question. Can you confirm that the new images are being completely inserted into the database then? It could be an insertion problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the images were transferred to the new server via ftp, it's possible that the transfer mode was not set correctly (i.e. ascii vs. binary). If you transfer a binary file in ascii ftp mode, it may interpret some of the bytes in the image as new-lines and try to convert them to windows (CRLF) or UNIX(LF), etc mode. This will usually corrupt the image so it isn't totally readable.

Comment: Not to be rude, but the code clearly mentioned `$_FILES` superglobal variable, which is only populated when a file is uploaded via a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

What MySQL library are you using? Certain versions of the MySQLi library have issues correctly retrieving blobs from the database.

I would verify that you are running the same versions of PHP and the relevant MySQL library on both servers.